# Show Magento cart details on Wordpress sites

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, session, wordpress

I have used Magento and WordPress sits together.My directory structer is like this `/Magento` and `/Magento/WordPress`.Now i am trying to get the cart details on WordPress site using above code but its not working.

```
<?php 

require_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
 echo 'cart items count: ' . $cart;
 echo ">>",Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty(); ?>
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: There's a module by FishPig that integrates WordPress with Magento very well; are you using this, or an equivalent? The issue you have is that when you run Mage::app() it initialises the sessions, so that you can't read what's been previously created in this environment.

Comment: @DanHanly Yes i am using Magento and WP integration.Like user login on one site it will automatically logged in on other one.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `Mage::app()` you are effectively initialising a new Magento application. This means that you don't have access to session data from your main application.

What I may suggest is that you either use a Module such as FishPig's WordPress Integrator or utilise asynchronous requests to the Main application.

**FishPig**
This module integrates the Magento theme and the WordPress theme fully meaning that you should have access to Magento methods in WordPress and vice versa. It can be a little tricky to configure, but from that point, your theme/templates should have access to Magento session data, even in a WordPress context. If this is indeed the module you're using, then I may suggest asking the developer for support, they've been helpful to my team in the past.

**Ajax**
Instead of running `Mage::app()` in WordPress, try using AJAX to Get the Session data from a controller on your existing application. I have no idea if this will work effectively, but in doing so, you will bypass the running of the `Mage::app()` command. You'll need to create a controller action to manage this, and then make a request for the data you need from a specific WordPress template.